# Xcode keyboard issue on scroll view

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.6

I have a scroll view on top single view. I have some textfields and `UIPickers` on it. Now I know how to make a keyboard go off when return is pushed. But, I am trying to get the keyboard off from textfield when the background is tapped or `UIpicker` is selected. I tried doing this...

**Interface :**

```
  - (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
```

**Implementation :**

> ```
> -(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
> {
>         [sender resignFirstResponder];
> }
>
> -(IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender
> {
>         [textField resignFirstResponder];
> }
> ```

But the problem is I cant make sroll view as control type to make it work..

Answer (score 1):

Try like this may be it helps you but not sure,

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
       if (![[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
           [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
       }
}
```

And for getting touch event on scrollview you have to take geasture recognization,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap)];
    [scroll addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

 -(void)singleTap{
        [text resignFirstResponder];
        //write whatever you want it.
    }
```

Comment: Hi sunny, I tried that, it works for UIView, but not Scroll view